# Nokogiri (Ruby): Extract tag contents for a specific attribute inside each node

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have a XML with the following structure

```
<Root>
   <Batch name="value">
      <Document id="ID1">
         <Tags>
            <Tag id="ID11" name="name11">Contents</Tag>
            <Tag id="ID12" name="name12">Contents</Tag>
         </Tags>
      </Document>

      <Document id="ID2">
         <Tags>
            <Tag id="ID21" name="name21">Contents</Tag>
            <Tag id="ID22" name="name22">Contents</Tag>
         </Tags>
      </Document>
   </Batch>
</Root>
```

I want to extract the contents of specific tags for each Document node, using something like this:

```
xml.xpath('//Document/Tags').each do |node|
   puts xml.xpath('//Root/Batch/Document/Tags/Tag[@id="ID11"]').text
end
```

Which is expected to extract the contents of the tag with id = "ID11" for each 2 nodes, but retrieves nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have a minor error in the xpath, you are using /Documents/Document while the XML you pasted is a bit different.

This should work:

```
//Root/Batch/Document/Tags/Tag[@id="ID11"]
```

My favorite way to do this is by using the #css method like this:

```
xml.css('Tag[@id="ID11"]').each do |node|
  puts node.text
end
```

Comment: I think you have confused XPath (`Tag[@id="ID11"]`) and CSS (`Tag#ID11`).

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that xpath used was wrong.

```
'//Root/Batch/Documents/Document/Tags/Tag[@id="ID11"]'
shoud be
'//Root/Batch/Document/Tags/Tag[@id="ID11"]'
```

Comment: You are right, the xpath was wrong, but still this will not cover what I'm trying to do. Basically I want to extract the contens of the tags grouped by Document.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working with the following code:

```
xml.xpath('//Document/Tags').each do |node|
   node.xpath("Tag[@id='ID11']").text
end
```